# Assigning number to char* via stringstream

Tags: c++, stringstream

can anyone explain to my why this code fails to assign the memory pointed to by c1 to 55, yet does for c2?  The code for assigning to c1 looks to be doing the same job as to c2, but in less steps.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main ()
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << 55;

    const char* c1 = ss.str().c_str(); // *c1 = \0

    // looks to be doing the same, but in stages
    std::string s = ss.str();
    const char* c2 = s.c_str(); // *c2 = "55"
}
```

Comment: `// *c1 = \0` How do you know? http://ideone.com/SAbOJ4

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to lie where you think it does... It works fine here: http://ideone.com/QgL1HI

Comment: I just tried this and get c1: c2:55.  Rudy, below, also gets the same as you.  Is this compiler specific I wonder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str()` is a temporary so it is destructed when the statement ends. At that point `c1` will be a dangling pointer. The difference between that and initializing with a `std::string` is that `std::string`'s constructor will *copy* the characters until `'\0'` into its buffer.

Comment: For the same reason: `c3` copies the text to its internal buffer *before* the temporary is deleted. FWIW, in my setup, both `c1` and `c2` produce `"55"`.

Comment: yes, someone else answering this also gets 55 for both.  Is this compiler dependant?

Comment: @user1408542 If you're attempting to dereference a dangling pointer (by printing it or whatever) that's Undefined Behavior. Your compiler doesn't have to output anything at all. It could throw up in your face if it wanted to. :)

Answer (score 0):

In the first version:
    const char* c1 = ss.str().c_str();
assigns c1 to point to an internal buffer within the stream ss.

The second version:
    std::string s = ss.str();
copies the entire buffer into string s.
Then
    const char* c2 = s.c_str();
assigns c2 to point to an internal buffer within the string s.

At this point, these two pointers will point to different buffers that contain the same characters.
If something else is written to the stream ss, it could reallocate its buffer.
In that case, c1 will be pointing to invalid memory, while c2 will still point to the valid buffer in string s.